# Display Missing Value in Chart Series in Conditional Palette in Cognos

Tags: charts, cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

My current scatter plot chart has a conditional palette for the series. I am able to set a specific color for each value except for missing values (or null values). I am able to see the text and color I have chosen for the missing values, but no points are shown in the plot. I have tried: setting missing values to ? in data format for my series item, trying numerous conditional/advanced conditional strings in the conditional palette (ex: using 'not in', 'is missing', = 'NULL')